# condition for equality of two matrics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given two matrices $A,B$ and a base $\{v_i\}$, I want to show that $A=B$. Is it sufficient to show $Av_i=Bv_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient.

Comment: The proposed duplicate posits a stronger condition, that $Av = Bv$ for *all* vectors, while here it is only known that $Av_i = Bv_i$ for $v_i$ belonging to a particular basis.  So formally there is a small gap between the two propositions, to show that knowing the matrix-vector products equal for all $v_i$ in a basis implies that equality for all vectors.  The gap, although small, perhaps deserves an Answer, esp. given that the earlier Question is now closed.